# DOMPDF sometimes work,and sometimes not

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

im using DOMPDF to make downloadable webpage.

but sometime it works, and Sometimes the page takes so long and finally displays "This site can not be reached, The connection was reset".

how to fix this?
its code error or its error on my webbrowser?

thanks :)

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model("Mproses");
}

public function download($db,$p,$id) {   
    // Load all views as normal
    $data['hasil'] = $this->Mproses->selectWhere($db,$p,$id);

    $this->load->view('hasil',$data);
    // Get output html
    $html = $this->output->get_output();

    // Load library
    $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');
    $today = date('D-M-Y h:i:s');
    // Convert to PDF
    $this->dompdf->load_html($html);
    $this->dompdf->render();
    $this->dompdf->stream($today.".pdf",array('Attachment'=>1));
    //or without preview in browser
    //$this->dompdf->stream("welcome.pdf");
}
```

thats my controller for dompdf

HTML file im tryin to download :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Hasil Pengecekan! <p class="pull-right"><a href="<?php echo URL;?>/index.php/home/diagnosa/" style="color:black;"><span class="fa fa-backward" aria-label="Kembali"></span> | <b>Kembali</b></a></p></h3>
    </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
<p style="color:black;">
<?php if(count($hasil)>0) { ?>

<?php foreach($hasil as $d) { ?>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <center>
    <h2 style="color:black;">Hasil Dari User : <?php echo $d->nama; ?></h2>
    </center>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <ul>
        <li style="color:black;"><h5>Penyakit</h5><p style="font-size:20px;"><?php echo $d->penyakit;?></p></li>
        <li style="color:black;"><h5>Pilihan</h5><p style="font-size:20px;">"<?php echo $d->pil;?>"</p></li>
        <li style="color:black;"><h5>Nilai CF</h5><p style="font-size:20px;"><?php echo $d->nilaicf;?> || <?php echo $d->nilaicf*100;?>%</p></li>
    </ul>

<?php } ?>

<?php } else { echo 'Maaf Data Yang Dicari Tidak Ada !'; } ?>
</p>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
    <center><?php echo anchor(URL.'index.php/topdf/download/riwayat/id_riwayat/'.$d->id_riwayat,'Download',array('style' => 'color:black;font-size:14px;padding:14px;border:1px black solid;')); ?></center>
    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: im using windows, and chrome (Version 60.0.3112.90)

Comment: Try without output class, but with returning parsed view as a string: `$html = $this->load->view('hasil', $data, true);`

Comment: @Tpojka its make my dompdf error, proof : [error](http://prntscr.com/g4n63r)

Comment: @alandsamuel did your pdf file has a lot of contents ie pages to render.

Comment: here my html page im tryin to render, http://prntscr.com/g4xhiq

Comment: You're using an older version of dompdf. Have you tried upgrading?

Comment: @BrianS im download latest version from their git page,

Comment: The error page you screen-capped indicates an exception in dompdf/include/frame_tree.cls.php. That path has not been valid since Dompdf 0.6.2. Current version as of this comment is 0.8.0 (ref the [releases page](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases/)).

Comment: If upgrading doesn't fix your problem can you post the HTML and not a screen capture of the HTML?

Comment: @BrianS done, check my question

Comment: I didn't have any problems rendering that particular HTML (despite the invalid bootstrap structure). A connection reset usually indicates an uncaught exception that crashed your web server. Possibly a memory overrun. You'll have to do more investigation on your end. Do you see any messages in the logs? Can you identify a difference in the content that's results in a reset vs. a successful render? You might want to start a discussion to work through the issue.